# CharArray joinToString keeps printing commas instead of S's

Tags: string, kotlin, char, chararray

```
fun printRoom() {
    println("Cinema: ")
    val rows = 7
    val columns = 8
    val seats = CharArray(columns) { 'S' }.joinToString { " " }
    for (i in 1..rows) {
        println("$i" + " " + seats)
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated. Im sure this is something simple im doing but I can't figure out why this keeps printing commas instead of S's

Comment: fixed. sorry and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CharArray.joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) has these parameters, all of which are optional and have default values:

```
fun CharArray.joinToString(
    separator: CharSequence = ", ", 
    prefix: CharSequence = "", 
    postfix: CharSequence = "", 
    limit: Int = -1, 
    truncated: CharSequence = "...", 
    transform: ((Char) -> CharSequence)? = null
): String
```

`joinToString` allows you to use your own separator, add your own prefix and postfix, have an optional custom limit on the joining, and have a custom string for when that limit is reached, and also optionally transform the `Char`s into some other `String` first, before joining them together.

By passing in `{ " " }`, you pass a lambda expression that simply returns the string `" "`. This corresponds to the `transform` parameter. Kotlin thinks that you want to transform every `Char` to the string `" "` first, and then join the `" "` together! Because you didn’t pass the `separator` parameter, the default value of `”, “` is used as the separator, which is why you see a lot of commas.

What you intended on doing is passing `" "` as the `separator` parameter. Don't write a lambda:

```
val seats = CharArray(columns) { 'S' }.joinToString(" ")
```

You can also be very explicit about this and say:

```
val seats = CharArray(columns) { 'S' }.joinToString(separator = " ")
```

If you don't mind a trailing space, [`repeat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/repeat.html) also works:

```
val seats = "S ".repeat(columns)
```

Comment: this was super informative and just what i needed to know. thanks!

Comment: got it! and thanks again! i gotta copy this into my personal notes now. lol